# Getting "Uncaught ReferenceError" despite the fact I have defined my function in my coffee script

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, onclick

I’m using Rails 4.2.4 and trying to create an “Edit” link that will invoke a jQuery function when clicked.  So I put this in my view …

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', '#', :onclick => "editMyObject(#{my_object_time.my_object.id})" %>
```

and then in my app/assets/javascripts/users.coffee script, I have

```
editMyObject = (id) ->
    # Populate the total for the day
    $.ajax
      url: "/my_objects/edit"
      type: 'GET'
      data: {id: id}
      success: (data) ->
        # populate my form here 
      error: ->
        alert "Something went wrong getting the data"
```

However, when I click on the link, I get this Javascript error …

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: editMyObject is not defined
```

I have verified that my coffee script is loaded on the page, but I can’t figure out what’s wrong with the above that makes the browser think the function is undefined.

Comment: You have wrong indentation and use a comment style `//` that does not exist in the coffee. Are these errors only in the question code?

Comment: No, the "//" was actually in my code so I replaced it witih "#".  However, I still get the error.  There are no console errors on page load, tho.  If indentation were a problem, wouldn't I get some kind of error in Rails or my JS console?

Comment: Can you call `editMyObject` from the Javascript console in your browser?

Comment: You won't receive any JS errors from invalid coffee because the JS code will not be created at all. I have not used coffee with ruby but you should look for errors during transpiling from coffee to JS, whenever it happens in your workflow.

Comment: Another hunch is that your coffee is not built in bare mode to prevent global variables. Try assigning the function to the window object and see if it helps, i.e. `window.editMyObject = ...`.

Comment: Hey, adding "window." in front of the function worked.  WTF?!  Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.